# Google Endpoints does not refresh the list from previous request even if I am creating a new object?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The issue is first time it is giving 1 value in list but from next time its returning previous values with the new value.
    # 1st request answer : { "number": [  "1" ]} 
    # 2nd request answer : { "number": [  "1",  "1" ]} 
    # 3rd request answer : { "number": [  "1",  "1",  "1" ]}
    # and so on
    # how come the new object's list is getting the values from the previous requests???

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

class testInput(messages.Message):
    number = messages.IntegerField(1)

class testOutput(messages.Message):
    number = messages.IntegerField(1, repeated=True)

class counter:
    count = []  
    def add(self, number):
        self.count.append(number)

@endpoints.api(name='testClass', version='v1.0')
class testClass(remote.Service):


@endpoints.method(testInput, testOutput,
                  path='countNow', http_method='GET',
                  name='countNow')

def countNow(self, request):

    #creating a new object of counter class
    counterObj = counter() # NOTE: IT SHOULD A NEW INSTANCE AND ITS ALL OBJECT MUST BE NEW
                           # e.g count list must be empty

    #getting the new number from request
    requestNumber = int(request.number)

    #creating an object of output class
    output = testOutput()

    #adding the number in list
    counterObj.add(requestNumber) # NOTE: ADDING A NUMBER IN THE LIST
                                  #HENCE: LIST SHOULD CONTAIN ONLY ONE VALUE IN IT AND ITS LENGTH MUST BE: 1

    #storing the list in output
    output.number = counterObj.count

    #returning output
    return output #RETURNING THE LIST AND IT SHOULD RETURN ONLY SINGLE VALUE IN LIST



application = endpoints.api_server([testClass])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Constructor `__init__` is needed to reinitialize.

```
class counter:

    def __init__(self):
        self.count = []    # instance variable unique to each instance

    def add(self, number):
        self.count.append(number)
```

In your case

```
class counter:
    count = []
```

This variable `count` class variable will share by all instances